# Change to next text area when one fills JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea

In my website, I added two text areas `t-area1` and `tarea2` with `maxlength = 50`. Is there any way to start typing from the second textarea automatically when the first one reach its maximum characters of 50? I would like to do this using JavaScript or jQuery. Please help....

Comment: Listen `oninput` on `#t-area1`, and in the handler check the length, if > 50, move focus to `#tarea2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
var maxlength = 50;
$("#t-area1").keyup(function(){
 var leng = $(this).val().length;
  if (leng>maxlength-1){
      $("#tarea2").focus();
  }
});
```

see working example http://jsfiddle.net/LKjuV/